# Include 'I' between link in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have this code in Node.js:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 900; i++) {
var location = "http://snackyrite.com/site.ashx?userid="+i;
```

However I need to add `&default=none` to the end of the link, so it'll look something like this: `var location = "http://snackyrite.com/site.ashx?userid="+i&default=none;`

This code does not work however - what's the correct solution?

Comment: Try `var location = "http://snackyrite.com/site.ashx?userid=" + i + "&default=none;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var location = "http://snackyrite.com/site.ashx?userid=" + i + "&default=none";
```

Will do perfectly.

Also, you do know it doesn't matter which order you send the URL parameters in, so you could also do:

```
var location = "http://snackyrite.com/site.ashx?default=none&userid=" + i;
```